# matlab find peak images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, binary-image

I have a binary image below:

[image]

it's an image of random abstract picture, and by using matlab, what I wanna do is to detect, how many peaks does it have so I'll know that there are roughly 5 objects in it.

As you can see, there are, 5 peaks in it, so it means there are 5 objects in it.

I've tried using `imregionalmax()`, but I don't find it usefull, since my image already in binary image. I also tried to use `regionprops('Area')`, but it shows wrong number since there is no exact whitespace between each object. Thanks in advance

Comment: use the rice demo.  It likely is in an image processing toolbox. [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-enhancement-and-analysis.html?refresh=true#zmw57dd0e734). You might do a "count" then "etch" then count, to get rid of "islands".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your they are peaks, they are vertical structures. So in this particular case, you case use [projection histograms](http://dis.um.es/~ginesgm/fip/intpro.html) (also know as [histogram projection function](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.85.6309&rep=rep1&type=pdf)): you make all the black pixels fall as if they were effected by gravity. Then you will find a curve of black pixels on the bottom of your image. Then you can count the number of peaks.

Here is the algorithm:

1. Invert the image (black is normally the absence of information)
2. [Histogram projection](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Signal.png)
3. Closing and opening in order to clean the signal and get [the final result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/SignalCleaned.png).
4. You can add a maxima detection to get the top of the peaks.

Comment: thanks in andvance, If I may know, what is the concept of projection histogram?

Comment: I've added the result. The projection histogram concept is explained into the two first links I shared.

Comment: what is the meaning by closing and opening by the way?

Comment: Closing and opening fill the small gaps and erase the small patterns. In this case, it cleans the shape of the different peaks. You can observe the difference between the histogram projection and the final result.

Comment: thank you soo muuch much much sir, now I can pass my bachelor degree, thanks a lot :') @FiReTiTi

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this would be to simply sum across the rows for each column and find the peaks of the result using [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html). In the example below, I have opted to use the inverse of the image which will result in positive peaks where the columns are.

```
rowSum = sum(1 - image, 1);
```

If we plot this, it looks like the bottom plot

[image]

We can then use `findpeaks` to identify the peaks in this plot. We will apply a 5-point moving average to it to help eliminate false peaks.

```
[peaks, locations, widths, prominences] = findpeaks(smooth(rowSum));
```

You can then select the "true" peaks by thresholding based on any of these outputs. For this example we can use `prominences` and find the more prominent peaks.

```
isPeak = prominences > 50; 
nPeaks = sum(isPeak)

   5
```

Then we can plot the peaks locations to confirm

```
plot(locations(isPeak), peaks(isPeak), 'r*');
```

[image]

If you have some prior knowledge about the expected widths of the peaks, you could adjust the [`smooth`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html) span to match this expected width and obtain some cleaner peaks when using `findpeaks`.

Using an expected width of 40 for your image, `findpeaks` was able to perfectly detect all 5 peaks with no false positive.

```
findpeaks(smooth(rowSum, 40));
```

[image]

Comment: thank you soo much for your solution, this really helps me much, Jazakallahu Khairan Katsira brother

Comment: hi, when I use findpeaks() function, it says that too many output argument for function findpeaks(). when I change it into 2 ouputs, it works but I dont know if it peaks, locations, widths, or prominences.

Comment: @BayuArasyi what Matlab version?

Comment: 2012 matlab version sir, I trying to figure out how to detect peak without any threshold, beacuse there already so many threshold in the pre-process. Is there any way to do so? do you know how to clip a signal as explained by brother FiReTiTi above?

Comment: 2012 matlab version sir, I trying to figure out how to detect peak without any threshold, beacuse there already so many threshold in the pre-process. Is there any way to do so? do you know how to clip a signal as explained by brother FiReTiTi above?